# Optimising SQL query using views (& indexes)

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, view

I'm having a hard time optimising a sql query that takes about 1 min to complete.  Here is the query :

```
SELECT mpg.ID_PROD_GARN, mpg.NO_PROD
FROM ACO.prime p
JOIN ACO.facture_compt fc
ON fc.id_factr = p.id_factr
JOIN ACO.V_CONTRAT vc
ON vc.NO_POLC = p.NO_POLC
JOIN ACO.MV_PRODUIT mp
ON mp.NO_PROD =vc.NO_PROD
JOIN ACO.MV_PROD_GARN mpg
ON mpg.NO_PROD   = mp.NO_PROD
WHERE p.id_prime =
( SELECT MAX(id_prime) AS prime FROM ACO.prime p WHERE p.no_polc='T3167978')
AND mpg.ID_PROD_GARN = '1238'
AND fc.cd_stat_factr = 'comp';
```

V_CONTRAT is a view and (if my understanding is correct) when joining the view in this way SQL is running trough all the rows to find the result.  I did a bit of research and found that indexing this view could speed up my query. So :

```
CREATE INDEX indx_no_produit ON ACO.V_CONTRAT(NO_PROD);
```

Unfortunately I get an error saying that I can't index a view SQL : ORA-01702 : you can't use that here. 
*Cause:    Among other possible causes, this message will be produced if an
           attempt was made to define an Editioning View over a view.
*Action:   An Editioning View may only be created over a base table.

So my question is how could I speed up this query elegantly?

Many thanks in advance!

Edit 1 : here is the explained plan

Plan hash value: 3107129748

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                            |     1 |   102 |       |   543K  (1)| 00:00:22 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                      |                            |     1 |   102 |       |   543K  (1)| 00:00:22 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                     |                            |     1 |    90 |       |   543K  (1)| 00:00:22 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                    |                            |     1 |    35 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                   |                            |     1 |    14 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MV_PROD_GARN               |     1 |     9 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_PROG                    |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |      BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS   |                            |     1 |     5 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |       BITMAP INDEX FAST FULL SCAN  | MV_PROD_NO_PROD_IDX        |       |       |       |            |          |
|   9 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | PRIME                      |     1 |    21 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PK_PRIME                   |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |       SORT AGGREGATE               |                            |     1 |    15 |       |            |          |
|  12 |        FIRST ROW                   |                            |     1 |    15 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX) | PRIME_NO_POLC_IDX          |     1 |    15 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |    VIEW                            | V_CONTRAT                  |     1 |    55 |       |   543K  (1)| 00:00:22 |
|  15 |     SORT UNIQUE                    |                            |    16M|  5011M|  2740M|   543K  (1)| 00:00:22 |
|  16 |      UNION-ALL                     |                            |       |       |       |            |          |
|* 17 |       HASH JOIN                    |                            |    16M|  2502M|       | 55963   (4)| 00:00:03 |
|  18 |        VIEW                        | index$_join$_016           |   103 |  1339 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |         HASH JOIN                  |                            |       |       |       |            |          |
|  20 |          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN      | PK_PROD                    |   103 |  1339 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN      | PRODUIT_COMBINE_IDX        |   103 |  1339 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER       |                            |    16M|  2293M|   261M| 55860   (4)| 00:00:03 |
|  23 |         INDEX FAST FULL SCAN       | ROL_INDEX1                 |    10M|   145M|       |  5703   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |         HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER      |                            |  6751K|   824M|   117M| 44540   (4)| 00:00:02 |
|  25 |          INLIST ITERATOR           |                            |       |       |       |            |          |
|* 26 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN         | ROL_CDROL_NOINTR_IDX       |  3975K|    72M|       |   756   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|* 27 |          HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER     |                            |  4192K|   435M|    90M| 40898   (3)| 00:00:02 |
|* 28 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL        | ROLE                       |  2881K|    57M|       | 14553   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|* 29 |           HASH JOIN                |                            |  2941K|   246M|   104M| 24558   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  30 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN    | INFO_BASE_DISTRIBUTEUR_FK1 |  4047K|    57M|       |  1925   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|* 31 |            HASH JOIN               |                            |  2961K|   206M|   136M| 20967   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  32 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL      | CONTRAT_ITER               |  4088K|    89M|       | 12159   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|* 33 |             HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER  |                            |  2961K|   141M|    32M|  7292   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|* 34 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN      | ROL_CDROL_NOINTR_IDX       |   933K|    22M|       |   890   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 35 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL     | CONTRAT                    |  2615K|    62M|       |  5781   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|* 36 |       HASH JOIN OUTER              |                            | 29239 |  2912K|       | 10228   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|* 37 |        HASH JOIN                   |                            | 29239 |  1941K|       |   285   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|  38 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL          | DISTRIBUTEUR               |  9142 | 91420 |       |    45   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|* 39 |         HASH JOIN                  |                            | 29239 |  1656K|       |   240   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  40 |          INDEX FULL SCAN           | PRODUIT_COMBINE_IDX        |   103 |  1030 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 41 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TPA_CONTRAT_MENSUEL        | 29239 |  1370K|       |   239   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  42 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL           | COUNTERPARTY               |  3547K|   115M|       |  9921   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|* 43 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | FACTURE_COMPT_INDEX9       |     1 |    12 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   6 - access("MPG"."ID_PROD_GARN"=1238)
   8 - filter("MPG"."NO_PROD"="MP"."NO_PROD")
  10 - access("P"."ID_PRIME"= (SELECT MAX("ID_PRIME") FROM "ACO"."PRIME" "P" WHERE "P"."NO_POLC"='T3167978'))
  13 - access("P"."NO_POLC"='T3167978')
  14 - filter("VC"."NO_POLC"="P"."NO_POLC" AND "MP"."NO_PROD"="VC"."NO_PROD")
  17 - access("PROD"."NO_PROD"="ITER"."NO_PROD" AND "PROD"."NO_VERS_PROD"="ITER"."NO_VERS_PROD")
  19 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  22 - access("ROLAUTRE"."ID_CONT"(+)="CONT"."ID_CONT" AND "ROLAUTRE"."NO_ITER_CONT"(+)="CONT"."NO_DERN_ITER")
  24 - access("ROLA"."ID_CONT"(+)="CONT"."ID_CONT" AND "ROLA"."NO_ITER_CONT"(+)="CONT"."NO_DERN_ITER")
  26 - access("ROLA"."CD_ROLE"(+)='ap' OR "ROLA"."CD_ROLE"(+)='debit' OR "ROLA"."CD_ROLE"(+)='emprun')
  27 - access("ROLPAY"."ID_CONT"(+)="CONT"."ID_CONT" AND "ROLPAY"."NO_ITER_CONT"(+)="CONT"."NO_DERN_ITER")
  28 - filter("ROLPAY"."CD_ROLE"(+)='pay' AND "ROLPAY"."IND_PAY_PRI"(+)='1')
  29 - access("ITER"."ID_INFO_BASE"="IB"."ID_INFO_BASE" AND "ITER"."NO_ITER_CONT"="IB"."NO_ITER_CONT" AND 
              SYS_OP_DESCEND("ITER"."NO_ITER_CONT")=SYS_OP_DESCEND("IB"."NO_ITER_CONT"))
  31 - access("ITER"."ID_CONT"="CONT"."ID_CONT" AND "ITER"."NO_ITER_CONT"="CONT"."NO_DERN_ITER" AND 
              SYS_OP_DESCEND("ITER"."NO_ITER_CONT")=SYS_OP_DESCEND("CONT"."NO_DERN_ITER"))
  33 - access("ROLP"."ID_CONT"(+)="CONT"."ID_CONT" AND "ROLP"."NO_ITER_CONT"(+)="CONT"."NO_DERN_ITER")
  34 - access("ROLP"."CD_ROLE"(+)='pren')
  35 - filter("CONT"."NO_SEQ_PROPO_SEL"=0)
  36 - access("CTRPY"."LAST_NAME"(+)="TCM"."CON_NOM_ASS_PRINC" AND 
              "CTRPY"."FRST_NAME"(+)="TCM"."CON_PRENOM_ASS_PRINC" AND "CTRPY"."DT_BIRTH"(+)="TCM"."CON_DATE_NAISS_ASS_PRINC")
  37 - access("TCM"."CON_NO_DISTRIBUTEUR"="A"."NO_DIST")
  39 - access("PROD"."NO_PROD"="TCM"."CON_CODE_PRODDUIT")
  41 - filter("TCM"."CON_VERSION_CONTRAT"=1)
  43 - access("FC"."ID_FACTR"="P"."ID_FACTR" AND "FC"."CD_STAT_FACTR"='comp')
```

Edit 2 : Here is the view V_CONTRAT

```
    SELECT   DISTINCT cont.ID_CONT,
                     cont.NO_POLC,
                     cont.cd_divs,
                     prod.no_prod,
                     prod.cd_cie_encai,
                     prod.cd_faml_cptb,
                     ib.no_dist_init,
                     CASE
                        WHEN ROLP.ID_ROLE IS NOT NULL THEN ROLP.NO_INTR
                        WHEN rola.no_intr IS NOT NULL THEN rola.no_intr
                        WHEN rolpay.no_intr IS NOT NULL THEN rolpay.no_intr
                        ELSE rolAutre.no_intr
                     END
                        AS NO_INTR_PRINC,
                     rolpay.no_intr AS NO_INTR_PAY
     FROM                        VIRAGE.CONTRAT CONT
                              INNER JOIN
                                 VIRAGE.contrat_iter iter
                              ON     iter.id_cont = cont.id_cont
                                 AND ITER.NO_ITER_CONT = CONT.NO_DERN_ITER
                                 AND CONT.NO_SEQ_PROPO_SEL = 0
                           INNER JOIN
                              VIRAGE.info_base ib
                           ON iter.id_info_base = ib.id_info_base
                              AND iter.no_iter_cont = ib.no_iter_cont
                        INNER JOIN
                           VIRAGE.produit prod
                        ON prod.no_prod = iter.no_prod
                           AND prod.no_vers_prod = iter.no_vers_prod
                     LEFT JOIN
                        VIRAGE.role rolp
                     ON     rolp.id_cont = cont.id_cont
                        AND rolp.no_iter_cont = cont.no_dern_iter
                        AND rolp.cd_role = 'pren'
                  LEFT JOIN
                     VIRAGE.role rola
                  ON rola.id_cont = cont.id_cont
                     AND rola.no_iter_cont = cont.no_dern_iter
                     AND (   rola.cd_role = 'ap'
                          OR ROLA.CD_ROLE = 'debit'
                          OR rola.cd_role = 'emprun')
               LEFT JOIN
                  VIRAGE.role rolpay
               ON     rolpay.id_cont = cont.id_cont
                  AND rolpay.no_iter_cont = cont.no_dern_iter
                  AND rolpay.cd_role = 'pay'
                  AND rolpay.ind_pay_pri = '1'
            LEFT JOIN
               VIRAGE.role rolAutre
            ON rolAutre.id_cont = cont.id_cont
               AND rolAutre.no_iter_cont = cont.no_dern_iter
   UNION
   SELECT   DISTINCT
            CAST (tcm.con_sequence AS NUMBER (10, 0)) AS id_cont,
            CAST (tcm.con_numero_contrat AS VARCHAR2 (20)) AS no_polc,
            CAST (vd.cd_divs_compt AS VARCHAR2 (11)) AS cd_divs,
            CAST (tcm.con_code_prodduit AS NUMBER (5, 0)) AS no_prod,
            CAST (prod.cd_cie_encai AS VARCHAR2 (1)) AS cd_cie_encai,
            CAST (prod.cd_faml_cptb AS VARCHAR2 (11)) AS cd_faml_cptb,
            CAST (tcm.con_no_distributeur AS VARCHAR2 (15)) AS no_dist_init,
            CAST (ctrpy.no_ctrpy AS NUMBER) AS no_intr_princ,
            CAST (ctrpy.no_ctrpy AS NUMBER) AS no_intr_pay
     FROM            TPA.TPA_CONTRAT_MENSUEL tcm
                  INNER JOIN
                     VIRAGE.produit prod
                  ON prod.no_prod = tcm.con_code_prodduit
               LEFT JOIN
                  counterparty ctrpy
               ON     ctrpy.last_name = tcm.con_nom_ass_princ
                  AND ctrpy.frst_name = tcm.con_prenom_ass_princ
                  AND ctrpy.dt_birth = tcm.con_date_naiss_ass_princ
            INNER JOIN
               v_distributeur vd
            ON tcm.con_no_distributeur = vd.no_dist
            WHERE TCM.CON_VERSION_CONTRAT=1
```

Comment: Might a materialized view help you? Do a bit of research on materialized views. "Fast refresh" may help, in addition to the fact that you can have indexes on a materialized view. You may need to discuss with your DBA if you are not the DBA.

Comment: The explain plan of the query is a must when optimizing any query. Please run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your_query`, then `SELECT * FROM table( DBMS_xplan.Display )`, and finally copy **the whole** result of last query - and please append it to the question **as a plain text - not a bitmap !!!** . More information regarding explain plans you can find here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm#i3305

Comment: You do not index a view - you need to create an index on the underlying tables' column in question.

Comment: You have some pretty big full table scans.   Fix the worst offenders first (index proper table column if possible), and see results.  Also, look at [DBMS_SQLTUNE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sqltun.htm#CHDGFHEC)

Comment: Could you also show a definition of `V_CONTRAT` view ? It looks from the explain plan that this view is the most costly in this query. The view is doing an unique sort of 16M rows, and the main query is picking only 1 single row from this view (1 single row from 16 millions).

Comment: A SQL Monitor report would be much more useful. The explain plan only tells you the estimated cardinality; what you need to be able to see is the *actual* cardinality.

Comment: I know this does not answer you question directly, but be very careful when you are doing OUTER JOINS on a constant. Very often what you mean semantically is to have the constant be a filter predicate, instead of a join clause. You will get different results.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes can only be created in tables.

Make sure you create an index for every single foreign key in every table. Oracle does not create them by default as other systems do.

Check also the performance of the sub-query and if it takes too long you should also create indexes for every attribute in the WHERE clause.

Don't forget that indexes need maintenance.